# Machinelearning, how to make a forecast from learning and training data

Tags: python

ive tried to do some machinelearning in python with pandas. My goal was to estimate the insurance costs of people based on their lifestyle. i got a nice database from kaggle. Doing training and testing on my dataset went quite well but now i want to make some forecast for a person and i dont know how to start.

i post what i have done so far with training and testing with a linear regression (i did also a lot of other stuff  like monte carlo, knearest, ...)
the result is
Accuracy on training set: 0.735
Accuracy on test set: 0.795

so how would you recommend to continue estimating the insurance cost of another person?

````
#Linear Regression
linreg = LinearRegression()

linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Accuracy on training set: {:.3f}".format(linreg.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Accuracy on test set: {:.3f}".format(linreg.score(X_test, y_test)))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already 'fit' the algorithm on X_train and y_train dataset, you can make predictions for X_test as follows:

```
predictions = linreg.predict(X_test)
```

Basically, `linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)` means fitting/training using `X_train` as inputs and `y_train` as (targeted) labels. On the other hand, `linreg.predict(X_test)` means using `X_test` as inputs to produce predictions, and `linreg.score(X_test, y_test)` means making predictions using `X_test` as inputs then comparing the predictions with the (targeted) `y_test` to get (accuracy) score.